# Use string to access multidimensional object?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a string: `'first.second.last'`

I also have an object:

```
{
    'first': {
        'second' : {
            'last': "value"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I access `"value"` using that string?

Comment: Yea, sorry. I don't use the right words sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this...

```
var o = {
    'first': {
        'second' : {
            'last': "value"
        }
    }
};
var s = 'first.second.last';
var val = s.split('.').reduce(function(p, c) {
    return p.hasOwnProperty(c) && p[c] || p;
}, o);
```

This will drill into your object and find the deepest key that matches. If instead, you want to return `null` for any failure to match a key, change the `reduce` callback to

```
function(p, c) {
    return p && p.hasOwnProperty(c) && p[c] || null;
}
```

If you need legacy support for `Array.prototype.reduce`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill

Comment: This will return unexpected results of the string doesn't match a path in the object.

Comment: @FelixKling It's a top-down search. It will return the deepest value that matches (which I mentioned in the answer). I suppose it could simply return `null` but OP would need to clarify their requirements

Answer (score 1):

That is not an array, it's an object. If you want to access `last` in that object, if there's a variable with the contents named `example`:

```
example['first']['second']['third']
```

If you want a dynamic setup where you're not sure of the depth try something like:

```
var myString = 'first.second.last'
var myObj = {
    'first': {
        'second' : {
            'last': "value"
        }
    }
}

myString.split('.').forEach(function(item) {
   myObj = myObj[item]    
})
```

In the end value will have your desired output. Someone might now a simple util or library that does exactly this, or a more functional way to apply this method, unfortunately nothing smarter comes to mind at this point.

Comment: I tried this out in console, didn't work.

Comment: try again. tested it worked.

Comment: Worked now, must have not copied a part of it.

Comment: it was my mistake, I had a minor bug there.

Comment: Destroying the original `myObj` reference doesn't sound like a good idea to me

Comment: I knew that when I wrote the solution, the focus was to explain how he user can navigate the tree. Your answer is a better one not only because of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the object similar to an array used the [] notation. If you split the string into it you can go `sample["first"]["second"]["third"]`

Therefore, this should work I think:

```
var sample = {
    'first': {
        'second' : {
            'last': "value"
        }
    }
}

var str = "first.second.last";
var current = sample;
str.split('.').forEach(function(prop) {
   current = current[prop];
})
return current;
```